# Base address, config files

Tags: wcf, app-config

My web service tests fine on localhost - so off to the real deal! Can someone help me make sense of the things I need to check and set. I want to know how to use the web.config for the baseAddress if needed, settings in the app.config on the web server.

```
<service name="WebServEnc.ServLib.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
      <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
      <endpoint contract="WebServEnc.Servlib.IServ" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="http://mysite.com" />

    </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hosting this in IIS or have the base address specified in your host, you don't need an address. You can just leave it as blank.

Look here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx

Comment: I don't think I am using IIS. I am uploading this to my hosting site via ftp to main directory.

Comment: The WCF service has to be hosted somewhere -- either in IIS or in a separate .NET application. If it's FTP'd somewhere, I would guess that you are hosting it in IIS.

Comment: OK, I have the app.config on the site and your saying I can leave the address empty - right? How about the endpoint node do I still need that? And as far as the app.config do I need the baseAddress in there? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing completely about how this is being hosted, I can't say for certain what you need. You always need the endpoint node, but you don't necessarily need a baseAddress.

Comment: Ok, In the app.config the baseAddress is just the domain name? I'll ask the hosting company about the type.

Comment: OK, so you should be ok without the `address` in the config since it's hosted in IIS.

Comment: I seem to be toggling between a runtime error and 500 internal server error. I use: **service name="WebServEnc.ServLib.Service"** in the service node, and in the **endpoint contract="WebServEnc.Servlib.IServ"**

Comment: I guess the next step is to make the transform for the web.config files since the website one gets overwritten by the service - any tips? I have read about as much as I can stand at the moment -> [link](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html)